# Sympy : How is it possible to simplify power of sum?

Tags: sympy

Considering an expression of this form:

```
x,y,n=sp.symbols("x y n",positive=True,real=True)
sp.Pow(x+y+x**2,n+1)*sp.Pow(x+2*y+4*y**3,-n-1)
```

how is it possible to simplify it to have a common power ?
(i.e.  `sp.Pow((x+y+x**2)/(x+2*y+y**3),n+1)` )

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/22546

Comment: @OscarBenjamin. Do you think that modifying the line 393 in powsimp.py (exp_c, exp_t = e.as_coeff_Mul(rational=True) *to* exp_c, exp_t = factor_terms(e).as_coeff_Mul(rational=True)
is a solution ? (Comment also added to your issue). It works for my problem but extensive tests are needed and I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same general problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70076847/sympy-powsimp-does-not-work-on-a-simple-example/70081037#70081037)

```
>>> var('z', positiv=True)
z
>>> expr = sp.Pow(x+y+x**2,n+1)*sp.Pow(x+2*y+4*y**3,-n-1)
>>> powsimp(expr.subs(n + 1, var('z',positive=1))).subs(z, n + 1)
((x**2 + x + y)/(x + 4*y**3 + 2*y))**(n + 1)
```