# Sympy : powsimp does not work on a simple example

Tags: sympy

Trying to solve my problem ([Sympy : How is it possible to simplify power of sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70073361/7462275)), I found a simple example where powsimp does not work.

In this case, the power simplification is done

```
x,y,n=sp.symbols("x y n",positive=True,real=True)
expr=sp.Pow(x,n)*sp.Pow(y,-n)
expr.powsimp()
```

But not in this case :

```
expr=sp.Pow(x,n+1)*sp.Pow(y,-n-1)
expr.powsimp()
```

Is it possible to do power simplification when the exponent is an expression (real and positive of course) ?

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/22546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`powsimp` should look for such cases, but until then, converting the exponent to a single variable (and subs will work out the relationship for you for the negated case):

```
>>> expr
x**(n + 1)*y**(-n - 1)
>>> powsimp(expr.subs(n + 1, var('z',positive=1))).subs(z, n + 1)
(x/y)**(n + 1)
```